# Opening a flash disk using command line to avoid getting virus

Tags: command-line, virus

Could my PC get a virus from a USB flash drive or external hard drive without opening that drive? So if we do our work from command line (such as xcopy, del, rmdir, ...) without opening any folder on that drive, we won't get any virus from it?

I've heard that Stuxnet was able to outspread even without opening the flash disk. Is it true?

Comment: If your host OS supports "auto run" of removable media then you could still be at risk.

Comment: Even without double clicking on the drive and opening it?

Comment: @livingbeing - Yes;  We can't confirm `Stuxnet` behavior since existence was limited to certain networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, malware **can** be put on a PC from a USB drive *or other USB peripheral, even an adapter*, without having to open a file. There is a fundamental issue with USB specifications in that the device identifies itself, so a USB  flash drive can identify itself as a keyboard and start "typing" commands. See https://srlabs.de/badusb/ and http://www.wired.com/2014/07/usb-security/ for examples, or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91lx4zv9Hms for a demo.